# VBA error"1004' on Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Tags: vba, excel

I greatly appreciate anyone who can help me fix my code.

I am very new to VBA and tried adapting the code below to work for my excel document. Unfortunately, I keep running into Error '1004' stating my selection to copy is to big for the are I want to paste it. I have search for days now and have no idea how to fix the code "Debug" tells me is wrong, Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown.

My spread sheet tracks progress on projects and when a project is completed (this is identified with the date the documents are signed) the entire row describing the project is move down below a header "Completed".

When a new project is initiated I have a "create New Project" button that inserts a new row above the existing projects that are still being worked on.

***My codes***:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'This Sub tranfers correspondence from the in progress line down underneath the completed line once a date is entered in the decision date column.

    If Target.Column = 23 Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Target.EntireRow.Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 220, 200)
            Selection.Cut

            'Locates the "completed" section and moves the cursor to just below the headings
            Cells.Find(What:="*Completed*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

            MsgBox ("Did you remember to upload all documents to shared drive")
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

AND.....

```
Sub Insert()
'
' Insert Macro   

'Insert row above Row 5
    Rows(6).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

Comment: First... don't use .Select or .Selectino if you can help it.  Copying a whole row to a single cell would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Will try to help clean this; haven't tested the code, but should be pretty straightforward, since you want to start with a whole row then end with a whole row:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns(23)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r as Long, i as Long
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        r = ActiveCell.Row
            With Rows(r)
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 220, 200)
                .Cut
            End With
            'Locates the "completed" section and moves the cursor to just below the headings
            i = Cells.Find(What:="*Completed*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
            Rows(i+2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            MsgBox ("Did you remember to upload all documents to shared drive")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am confused by your line:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

What were you trying to do?  The code I modified has the row being inserted 2 below the Completed cell row.